# Validating a SimpleForm field within React-Admin

Tags: react-admin

I'm using an old version (2.9) of the React-Admin framework and having trouble validating a SimpleForm field.
I realize upgrading to a newer version is the way to go, but that will be a while.
I'm validating a field in a SimpleForm.

My `validatefunction` (below) returns an integer, 0 or above.
I want the validation to *pass* when that value is 0, but *fail* when the value is > 0. Currently, the form vails validation in all cases. Instead, I want it only fail when the return value is > 0.

Is there some way to specify that using some kind of expression on the `validate` line in the SimpleForm below?

```
const MyComponent = ({ dispatch, dataProvider, ...props }) => {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <SimpleForm>
                ...
                <ReferenceInput
                    source="somefield"
                    validate={[ required(), validatefunction ]}
                >
                    <SelectInput optionText="name" />
                </ReferenceInput>
                ...
            </SimpleForm>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

A better approach might be for my `validatefunction` to return `undefined` when the validation passes. But for reasons outside the scope here I haven't yet gotten that working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `validateFunction` should return a string if there is an error.

```
const validatefunction = (value) => {
   const validatorValue = oldValidateFunction(value);
   if (validatorValue > 0) {
      return 'error this does not validate';
   }
}
```

See https://marmelab.com/react-admin/doc/2.9/CreateEdit.html#per-input-validation-custom-function-validator for the documentation of input validators.

Comment: Thanks! The issue I'm having is my validator uses React-Admin's Query component and it's always returning a value. (I can't figure out how to get Query to return undefined.) Thus, the validation always thinks there's an error. To deal with this, I wondered if, within SimpleForm, a certain value (0) returned from the validator can be treated as cleared.

Comment: No, whatever value returned by a validator is treated like an error message